# Converting one-hot encoded data to aggregate in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have age columns like so that are dummy encoded.
How can I aggregate the information so i can get counts in dplyr

Input:

```
age_010 age_11-20 age_2130 age_3140 age_41-50 age_5160
0       1         0        0        0         0
0       0         1        0        0         0
0       0         0        1        0         0
0       1         0        0        0         0
0       0         0        0        0         1
```

Expected Output:

```
age           n
age_010       0 
age_11-20     2
age_2130      1
age_3140      1
age_41-50     0 
age_5160      1
```

Answer (score 2):

We may do the column wise `sum`

```
v1 <- colSums(df1)
data.frame(age = names(v1), n = unname(v1))
```

-output

```
 age n
1   age_010 0
2 age_11.20 2
3  age_2130 1
4  age_3140 1
5 age_41.50 0
6  age_5160 1
```

---

If we want the `tidyverse`, do the `sum` `across` all the columns and then reshape to 'long' with `pivot_longer`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
   summarise(across(everything(), sum)) %>%
   pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_to = 'age', values_to = 'n')
# A tibble: 6 × 2
  age           n
  <chr>     <int>
1 age_010       0
2 age_11.20     2
3 age_2130      1
4 age_3140      1
5 age_41.50     0
6 age_5160      1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(age_010 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), age_11.20 = c(1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), age_2130 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), age_3140 = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), age_41.50 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), age_5160 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L
))
```